# Nuxeo E-mail archive facility

Tags: configuration, email, nuxeo

http://blogs.nuxeo.com/lounge/2009/05/email-archive-box.html

The above link tells that e-mail archive feature can be enabled in Nuxeo platform. Can you please help me to enable this feature in nuxeo cmf 1.8 or Nuxeo DM 5.4.2 platform. Tell me where I can avail the above facility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find the required information here:
http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/9oKN

Comment: Hi, I need to know about the e-mail archive facility like If I need to place my e-mails inside my Gmail account into the Nuxeo mailbox folder?? Isthere any way for that?